# tomcat: redirect request to webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, redirect, web-applications, jax-rs

I have a tomcat running, on which I have two residing `webapps`, `webapp-1` and `webapp-1.1`. I am looking for a way to redirect requests for `webapp-1` to `webapp-1.1`. On top of it, I want to be able to redirect calls for `webapp-1` to `webapp-1.2` on an update of `webapp-1.1` easily.

Currently I have to copy `webapp-1.1` as `webapp-1` and on update `webapp-1.2` as `webapp-1` to have it called directly. But with this technique the version information of the webapp is lost.

What I am actually looking for is a way to have just webapps `webapp-1.1` and `webapp-1.2` and not even `webapp-1`. There should be a redirect directly made by tomcat.

Is there a way to handle this? I found several methods on the net which does not seem to work for me because I need to be flexible on update of the webapp and I don't want the redirect be made by the `webapp-1` itself (like with a `ContainerRequestFilter` and `302 response`) if possible but rather by some other way which looks at a configuration (file) on the server for the redirect path.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @bilesh.g I didn't understand your edit, so I changed title for (hopefully) better readability

Comment: See my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401153/non-static-webapp-alias) on a non-static webapp-alias as a solution for me.