# Non-static webapp alias

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, web-applications

I would like to know, if there is a clean way to have a request answered by a webapp whose name does not appear in the request url. In a way, the url should be an alias of the webapp. Also, the alias should not be static or fixed with this single webapp but rather I need to be able to change the webapp behind the alias easily for version increments.
The things, that come to my mind are

- build a "facade" webapp to redirect requests
- rename the complete webapp

Both ideas don't lead to the desired result. I would like to have a more lightweight solution.

Is this possible?

Comment: Generally this is achieved with front end networking systems, either a load balancing device or an apache/nginx installation that does rewrites.

Comment: @Affe ok, but this sounds like a bit of an overhead? I don't want my entire traffic redirected, just requests for a single webapp inside my container. Could you maybe elaborate on a simpe use case scenario?

Comment: What do you currently use as a front end?  Are you exposing tomcat directly to the internet?  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: Well, tomcat webapps (webservices) are referenced internally by java or php applications primarily. Also, some of the webapps are intended to be used within an API accessible from outside, thats why there is the need for the alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the post from Alexander I found the right track but I used some additional work, which is more or less the facade webapp mentioned in point 1) from my original question. I will show my entire approach for anyone interested:

First, I have all my standard webapps deployed in `/tomcat/webapps` with one standard `context.xml` and `autoDeploy` mode on. To catch all other requests, that do not match one of the deployed contexts, I set up a new webapp which acts as a default webapp for not matched requests. Let's call it `dispatcher-app`.

To make this one work, I have to set it as `ROOT`. To deploy it under its original name, I located it under `/tomcat/webapps2` and its associated `context.xml` in `/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml`. It's necessary to put it outside of `/webapps` to prevent double deployment in tomcat with the autoDeploy mode used for the other webapps. Additional info on that can be found here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context#Naming

The `ROOT.xml` looks like this:

```
<Context
    path=""
    docBase="/path/to/tomcat-base/webapps2/dispatcher-app"
    crossContext="true"
/>
```

In web.xml of the `dispatcher-app` make sure, it uses

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

The `dispatcher-app` inside looks for the original path that was requested by the user using `uriInfo.getAbsolutePath()`. It then matches the application from the url with applications that run in tomcat, known from a custom configuration file. If there is a match, the configuration file knows, to which application the forward should be made. For example, the user requests `myserver/webapp-1/test?param=value`, and is forwarded to `myserver/webapp-1.1.2/test?param=value`. The webapp to forward to can be updated in the configuration file manually if application version changes.

The actual forward should be made using

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher=servletContext.getRequestDispatcher(redirectTo);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

because the forward will not be visible to the user.

As I could not make that run (see [Cross-context request forwarding in tomcat results in java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.TracingLogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558166/cross-context-request-forwarding-in-tomcat)), I simply used a 307 redirect for now.

```
return Response.status(307).location(new URI(redirectTo)).build();
```

The drawback of this one is, the browser will show the redirect URL in the address bar.

**UPDATE:**
The `RequestDispatcher` works now, just not for this special case/webapp mentioned above. So I prefer that over the redirect approach.

One thing to note is, that container-based authentication (e.g. `realm`) on the second webapp will not be effective (as we do the forward 'behind' tomcat facade) so the `dispatcher-app` needs an authentication method itself or authentication needs to be made with another mechanism, such as a `RequestFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with tomcat means only, you can statically map your webapp's path in tomcat `context.xml` defining a context and map the `request path` ("path") to a `webapp dir` ("docBase").

Just add this to your `<tomcatDir>/conf/context.xml`:

```
<Context 
  path="" 
  docBase="/<pathToYourWebapp>/<yourApp>" 
/>
```

This has the side-effect that you can only have one webapp, of course, because every request und `/` is mapped to your webapp.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes for further information.

Comment: This would have the drawback, that I had to maintain one context.xml file per exposed webapp and modify them, if the webapp behind the context file changes. Am I right? Also I think, I would need to restart tomcat after those modifications.

Comment: If you add this `<Context/>` node to **the** context.xml (`conf/context.xml`), it would be **one node** per webapp in the **one and only context.xml**. I think you can also add one context.xml per webapp in `conf/Catalina/localhost/<webappName>`, but that's a different story. The other way was suggested by @Affe ("... a load balancing device or an apache/nginx") - that would be without configuring tomcat, but with configuring something before